# Question about identity and zero mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Definition: Let V and W be vector spaces, and let $T: V \rightarrow W$ be linear. Define the null space N(T) of T to be the set of all vectors x in V such that $T(x)=0$.
>
> Define the range R(T) of T to be the subset of W consisting of all images of vectors in V.

Here is the example I have question about:

> Let V and W be vector spaces, and let $I:V \rightarrow V$ and $T_0: V \rightarrow W$ be the identity and zero mapping. Then $N(I)={0}$, $R(I)=V$, $N(T_0)=V$, and $R(T_0)={0}$

I have trouble understanding these:

> $N(I)={0}$, $R(I)=V$, $N(T_0)=V$

Can someone explain why these results make sense?

Comment: If $I x = 0$ then $x=0$ so $N(I) = \{0 \}$. Since $Ix = x$ we see that $R(V) = V$. Since $T_0 x = 0$ for all $x$ we have $N(T_0) = V$ and since $T_0 x = 0$ for all $x$ we have $R(T_0) = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *null space* of a linear map $\textsf{T} : \textsf{V} \to \textsf{W
}$ is the set of all vectors that are mapped to zero under $\textsf{T}$, that is, is the set of all vectors $v$ in $\textsf{V}$ such that $\textsf{T}(v) = \textbf0$. Also, the *range* of $\textsf{T}$ is the set of all vectors $w$ in $\textsf{W}$ so that they can be writen as $w = \textsf{T}(v)$ for some $v$ in $\textsf{V}$.

Now, recall that the identity map $I: \textsf{V} \to \textsf{V}$ is the function that each vector in $\textsf{V}$ assigns to itself. With this, since the zero vector is the *only* vector such that $I(\textbf{0}) = \textbf{0}$, we see that the null space of $I$ is $\{\textbf{0}\}$, and since any $v\in\textsf{V}$ can be writen as $v = I(v)$, the range of $I$ is the whole space $\textsf{V}$, right?

Similarly, since the zero map $\textsf{T}_0 : \textsf{V} \to \textsf{W}$ is the function that assigns to each vector in $\textsf{V}$ the zero vector of $\textsf{W}$, *every* $v\in\textsf{V}$ satisfy $\textsf{T}_0(v) = \textbf0$, hence, the null space of $\textsf{T}_0$ must be all $\textsf{V}$ and the range of $\textsf{T}_0$ must be only $\{\textbf0\}$, since $\textbf0$ is the only vector in its image.